# HTML form not passing values to MySQL query

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have the code below, which I want to use to combine the **month** and **date** values of the drop-down list, in a MySQL query, so I can filter by date.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<label class="custom-select">
<select name="q">
<option value="">Month:</option>
<option value="MONTH(post_date) = 1">Jan</option>
<option value="MONTH(post_date) = 2">Feb</option>
<option value="MONTH(post_date) = 3">Mar</option>
<option value="MONTH(post_date) = 4">Apr</option>
<option value="MONTH(post_date) = 5">May</option>
<option value="MONTH(post_date) = 6">Jun</option>
<option value="MONTH(post_date) = 7">Jul</option>
<option value="MONTH(post_date) = 8">Aug</option>
<option value="MONTH(post_date) = 9">Sep</option>
<option value="MONTH(post_date) = 10">Oct</option>
<option value="MONTH(post_date) = 11">Nov</option>
<option value="MONTH(post_date) = 12">Dez</option>
</select>
</label>
<label class="custom-select">
<select name="q">
<option value="">Year:</option>
<option value="AND YEAR(post_date) = 2013">2013</option>
<option value="AND YEAR(post_date) = 2014">2014</option>
<option value="AND YEAR(post_date) = 2015">2015</option>
</select>
</label>
<input name="submit2" id="submit2" style="margin-left: 15px;" type="submit" value="Pesquisar">
</form>

<?php 
if ($_POST['q'] == '') {
    $q = 'YEAR(post_date) = YEAR(CURDATE())';
}
else {
    $q = $_POST['q'] ;
}

$query=mysql_query("SELECT *, 'Yield'
FROM wp_posts
WHERE p.post_status = 'publish' AND ".$q." 
LIMIT 0, 2500")
?>
```

This is not working, I get the error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND YEAR(post_date) = 2014

Can someone help? Thanks

Comment: It's the quotes in `'Yield'` remove them or better yet, use backticks (column names cannot be wrapped in quotes). Plus, possibly `AND ".$q."` which could read as `AND '".$q."'`

Comment: What is the actual SQL being executed?

Comment: The error is: error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND YEAR(post_date) = 2014

Comment: Oh good god. Not just a basic [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability, but actually **INJECTING** SQL on **PURPOSE**... I'd -infinity if I could...

Comment: `var_dump($sql)`, and you'll see you're doing `WHERE ... AND AND ...`

Comment: You are using `p.post_status` but never declare `p`.

Comment: [`2 out of 3 birds were not seriously hurt during the making of this comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21892922/html-form-not-passing-values-to-mysql-query#comment33152979_21892922)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your month and year `<select>` boxes have `name="q"` so only the last one (year in this case) is passed to your PHP.

Name them `month` and `year` respectively as access them using `$_POST['month']` and `$_POST['year']`

**HTML**

```
<select name="month">
    <option value="01">January</option>
</select>
<select name="year">
    <option value="1952">1952</option>
</select>
```

**PHP**

```
$q = $_POST['month'].'-'.$_POST['year']; // this gives you   01-1952
```

Comment: Is there any chance of using just one name"q", the problem is I'm using the same $_POST['q'] for 3 input boxes for the same query.

Comment: Your HTML form absolutely needs to use different names unless you are passing arrays but that's too complex for this discussion. Please see my edit for properly using `month` and `year`

Answer (score 1):

This might not fix it but if you change the quotes to this

```
$query=mysql_query('SELECT *, Yield
FROM wp_posts
WHERE p.post_status = publish AND '.$q.' 
LIMIT 0, 2500');
```

it might work.  I think the problem could be with your using two different types of quotes in the statement.

Comment: the problem is not in quotes, the error mentions something different. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You have two AND's in your query and addition you use alias p without defining it try:

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT *, 'Yield'
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE post_status = 'publish' ".$q." 
LIMIT 0, 2500");
```

I suggest change sql driver to more secure (with binding parameters to prepared statements)